# Orange - how to load one file to two separate tables?

Tags: python, python-2.7, orange

I want to read data from one file, load it to two `Orange.data.Table`s and change column names in one of these tables. Here's the code:

```
import Orange
data = Orange.data.Table("sample_data.tab")

data2 = Orange.data.Table(data)
data2.domain = Orange.data.Domain(data.domain)

for inst in data2.domain:
    data2.domain[inst].name = '__' + data2.domain[inst].name
```

but, for some reason, column names change in *both* tables. How to change column names in only one of the tables?

Answer (score 1):

Orange reuses column descriptors. This is needed so that if you load data from two files and use one for fitting a model, you can use the other file to testing it. Generally, if the column has the same name and type, it will also have the same descriptor.

You can avoid this by adding `createNewOn=0` when loading the data.

```
d1 = Orange.data.Table("iris")
d2 = Orange.data.Table("iris", createNewOn=0)
```

The whole story is described here: http://docs.orange.biolab.si/reference/rst/Orange.data.table.html and here: http://docs.orange.biolab.si/reference/rst/Orange.feature.descriptor.html#variable-descriptor-reuse.

There is an error in documentation: `create_new_on` should be `createNewOn`. (My example above is correct.)

If the data is already loaded, like in your case, changing the descriptors for one table without losing the data is more complicated. If you *really* need it, I can show you how, but I guess you don't. If you do so, you'd get two completely unrelated tables.